# How can I resolve error: no such file or directory

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a FASTA file using perl and I want to put each header as the key and each sequence as the value into hash. I wrote my codes but I got error: no such file  or directory
I have my fasta file and perl file in the same directory.

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $file = "chicken.fa";
open (my $READ, "<$file") || die "Cannot open $file: $!.\n";

my %seqs = ();
my $header = '';

while (<$READ>){
    my $line = $_;
    chomp($line);
    if ($line eq "") { next; }
    if ($line =~ /^>.+/){
        $line = $header;
    } else {
        $seqs{"$header"} .= $line;
    }
}
close ($READ);
```

Comment: Use bioperl's fasta reader modules instead of trying to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 3):

If you are certain that a file called `chicken.fa` does exist, there are several possibilities.

1. Wrong directory. As written your script will try to find the `chicken.fa` file in the same directory that you are running the Perl script from. If the file is actually in a different directory, it won't be found.

   ```
   if (! -f 'chicken.fa') {
       warn "'chicken.fa' doesn't exist in this directory!";
   }
   ```

Even if your perl script and input file are in the same directory, Perl won't find your file *unless you also start the perl script from that directory*. That is, this will work

```
cd /directory/where/the/stuff/is
perl the_script.pl
```

but this won't

```
cd /some/other/directory
perl /directory/where/the/stuff/is/the_script.pl
```

2. Permission. You may not have the required permissions, in this case read permission, to open the file.

   ```
   if (! -r 'chicken.fa') {
       warn "Don't have read permission on 'chicken.fa' file!";
   }
   ```
3. Bad symbolic link. Maybe `chicken.fa` is a symbolic link to another location, and that location is not a valid file.

   ```
   if (-l 'chicken.fa' && ! -f readlink('chicken.fa')) {
       warn "'chicken.fa' is an invalid symbolic link";
   }
   ```